# two sql table differences

Tags: sql

I am trying to do this exercise: The search for differences between two data sets is required, the first is from the FIGL table and the second table is the SALES, the two tables coincide in the CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DATE, VALUE. Write an SQL statement that allows you to find only the differences between the two tables, the result should not deliver records where the difference is less than 1000 pesos, keep in mind that one table can have more documents than another.

and what I've done so far is this:

```
select figl.*, ventas.* 
FROM ventas,figl
WHERE figl.id_cliente != ventas.id_cliente 
AND figl.id_cuenta!=ventas.id_cuenta
AND figl.id_documento!=ventas.id_documento
AND figl.fecha!=ventas.fecha
AND ABS(figl.valor-ventas.valor)>1000
y mis tablas son estas:

CREATE TABLE figl(
id_cliente integer primary key, 
id_cuenta integer(100), 
id_documento integer(100),
fecha date,
valor integer(100)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas(
id_cliente integer primary key, 
id_cuenta integer(100), 
id_documento integer(100),
fecha date,
valor integer(100)
);

INSERT INTO figl
(id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento,fecha,valor)
VALUES
(1, 3001, 1010217112,'2020-06-18',850000);

INSERT INTO figl
(id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento,fecha,valor)
VALUES
(2, 3002, 1014244609,'2020-06-20',853000);

INSERT INTO figl
(id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento,fecha,valor)
VALUES
(3, 3003, 1014244610,'2020-06-21',852000);

INSERT INTO ventas
(id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento,fecha,valor)
VALUES
(1001, 3001, 1010217112,'2020-06-18',851500);

INSERT INTO ventas
(id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento,fecha,valor)
VALUES
(2, 3002, 1014244609,'2020-06-20',850500);
```

Comment: Can you please translate in english?

Comment: En inglés por favor

Comment: @Dharman : That is funny, I don't understand spanish!

Comment: I am trying to do this exercise: searching for differences between two data sets is required, the first is from the FIGL table and the second table is SALES, the two tables have the same attributes CLIENT_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, DOCUMENT_ID, DATE, VALUE. Write an SQL statement that allows you to find only the differences between the two tables, the result should not deliver records where the difference is less than 1000 pesos, please note that one table can have more documents than another.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [INSTERSECT-OPERATOR](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php).

Your question is somewhat ambiguous therefore i have to assume some things:

do the costs have to be higher than 1000 or do you only want to get all distinct records which have the same id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento, fecha **but** valor can vary by up to 1000?

Assuming you need to get the different records from two tables which have costs >1000 your query would look somewhat like this:

```sql
SELECT id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento, fecha, valor FROM ventas where valor <1000
INTERSECT
SELECT id_cliente, id_cuenta, id_documento, fecha, valor FROM figl where valor <1000
```